# Free product as automorphism group of graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two groups. We define following graph $X$. The set of vertices is the left cosets $gA$ and $gB$ where $g\in A*B$ (By $A*B$, I mean the free product of $A$ and $B$). The edges of the graph X correspond to the elements of $A*B$, and we use $e_g$ to denote the edge associated to $g\in A*B$. This does have the unfortunate consequence that the edge associated to the identity is $e_e$. Each edge is associated to an unordered pair of vertices: $\operatorname{Ends}(e_g) = \{gA,gB\}$. I want to show that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)=A*B$. I can show that $A*B$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)=A*B$, but I do not any idea for the converse.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Why do you believe it is true? (I may have misunderstood, but at first sight this graph looks like a tree, and I would expect it's automorphism group to be much bigger.)

Comment: DerekHolt this is part of my homework and the reference is Groups, graphs and trees by John Meier.

Comment: This actually depends on how you define $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$, because if you allow it to act by inversions (mapping edges in your graph to their inverse edges, or changing the direction of edges depending on how things are defined) then $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ cannot be equal to $A\ast B$.

Comment: user1729 as you can see in definition of X, the graph X is an undirected graph.

Comment: @user108209 You do not define edges in your graph, so it is not clear if you are discussing a "directed" or an "undirected" graph.

Comment: @user1729, I edited my question as exactly in my problem.

Comment: You need the word "unordered" (although this is perhaps implied, but you need it to be clear). I have added this in. (Also - I fixed your $\TeX$. Use `\operatorname` rather than `\rm`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16037/discussion-between-user108209-and-user1729).

Comment: @user108209 Unfortunately, chat doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found it. this is as the same as theorem 3.28 of groups, graphs and trees(page 81). I was wondering if you exactly explain me that how the author shows that?

Comment: @user108209 The key point, I believe, is that the tree in Theorem 3.28 is *biregular*. Basically, you colour the vertices corresponding to cosets of $A$ *black* and those corresponding to the cosets of $B$ *white*. Then the trick of switching the vertices (which is the point of my answer, below) does not work (because this is not an automorphism of the biregular tree).

Comment: Also, this is not the place for explaining proofs from books. If you find a step in the proof which you do not understand then you can ask it here, but John Meier is a good, clear writer, so my "explanation" would be inferior to his!

Comment: @user1729 I think by symmetries, he means a subgroup of automorphism of tree such that preserves the color of each part(preserves bipartite structure).

Comment: @BabakMiraftab Exactly - he means the automorphism group of the undirected bipartite tree, rather than of the tree. These are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @user1729 I have not seen this book, but I think the literature of this book is little bit strange. Isn't it?

Comment: @BabakMiraftab Hmm, I am not sure. It is meant for (advanced) undergraduate students, so I suppose it is trying to cut corners and not get bogged down by over-formalism. But it is a good book, and very readable! A nice, gentle introduction to geometric group theory...

Comment: But I prefer introduction to group theory by Oleg Bogopolski. It is very readable, and I guarantee it.

Comment: @BabakMiraftab That was on my to-buy list for a while (because the final bit was on train-tack maps). Perhaps I will finally buy it soon...

Comment: @BabakMiraftab I may have been slightly confused earlier. I have edited my answer thought - basically this can never happen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\neq A\ast B$. First, note that the tree you construct is a biregular tree, where $A$ acts by fixing a vertex and permuting its edges (and the trees extending from these edges). The group $B$ acts similarly, and this extends to a faithful action of $A\ast B$.

**Theorem:** $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\neq A\ast B$

> To see that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\neq A\ast B$, note that in general the tree which you construct contains $S_{|A|}\ast S_{|B|}$ in its automorphism group, because vertices have valency $|A|$ and $|B|$ respectively (and the adjacent edges can be be permuted). By a relatively simple argument, $S_{|A|}\ast S_{|B|}$ does not embed into $A\ast B$ (if either of $A$ or $B$ is infinite, just look at cardinality!). Hence, the isomorphism does not hold.

A slightly different, but fundamentally identical, way of seeing that the isomorphism cannot hold is as follows: Take two non-isomorphic groups $A_1$ and $A_2$ of the same order. Then $A_1\ast B\not\cong A_2\ast B$, but the graph $X$ you obtain is in each case the same. For example, $P=C_4\ast C_3$ and $Q=(C_2\times C_2)\ast C_3$ both give the same tree, and these actions extend to a natural, faithful action of $S_4\ast C_3$ on the same tree (where $S_4$ permutes the four adjacent edges of some valency $4$ vertex). Derek Holt pointed this out in the comments, below (which lead to the above proof).

Lee Mosher has pointed out in the comments that the following result also holds. This implies that above theorem.

**Theorem:** If one of $A$ or $B$ has order greater than two then $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ has cardinality strictly greater than that of $A\ast B$.

Note that if both $A$ and $B$ have order precisely two then you are looking at a combinatorial line, which has automorphism group $A\ast B\cong D_{\infty}$.

One way of proving this result is as follows.

> If either of $A$ or $B$ is infinite (suppose, without loss of generality, $A$ is infinite with $|A|\geq|B|$) then this holds because the above argument proves that $S_{A}$ embeds into $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$, and it is well-known that $|S_{A}|>|A|\geq|A\ast B|$.
>
> Suppose both $A$ and $B$ are finite, with $|A|>2$. We wish to prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is uncountable, so we shall find an uncountable subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$. Begin by fixing a vertex $v$ which is associated to a coset of $A$, and enumerate all but one of its child vertices, labelling them $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{|A|-1}$. Note that these labelled vertices are $B$-vertices. A permutation of these children gives an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$. We can do the same labelling with the $A$-descendants (and their children) of each of the $v_i$. Then, enumerate the $A$-vertices apart from in the subtree tree we are ignoring. Then the elements of the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ which fixes the vertex $v$ and which fixes the subtree we are ignoring can thus be represented by an element of the Cartesian product $S_{|A|-1}\times S_{|A|-1}\times\cdots$. This Cartesian product is uncountable, hence $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is also uncountable.

Note that because the elements of $A\ast B$ are only of finite length, in the above argument elements of $A\ast B$ have finite support in the Cartesian product (and hence we do not violate the fact that there are only countably many elements of $A\ast B$).

---

The comments below the question imply that the OP is interested in Theorem 3.28 (p81) of John Meier's book *Groups, Graphs and Trees*. The exact theorem is as follows. A *biregular* tree is an infinite bipartite tree where all vertices of a specific class have the same valancy.

**Theorem** Every free product of groups $A\ast B$ can be realized as a group of symmetries of a biregular tree $\mathcal{T}$, and a fundamental domain for this action consists of a single edge and its two vertices. Further, if $A$ and $B$ are both finite, this tree is $\mathcal{T}_{|A|, |B|}$.

However, this theorem is just saying $A\ast B\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(X)$. It says nothing about an isomorphism.

Comment: I am finding this confusing. The fact that the tree is $\mathcal{T}_{|A|, |B|}$ when $A$ and $B$ are finite, suggests that the tree, and hence its automorphism group, depends only on $|A|$ and $|B|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, you are right. For example, $C_4\ast C_3$ and $(C_2\times C_2)\ast C_3$ act like this on the same tree, and indeed $S_4\ast C_3$ also acts on this tree. The statement of the theorem is about "group of symmetries of the tree", so they are just saying that the free product injects into the automorphism group, not that it is the automorphism group.

Comment: To add to this, if $A,B$ are nontrivial and if they are countable (e.g. finite) then $A*B$ is countable, but if in addition at least one of $A$ or $B$ has cardinality $\ge 3$ then $\text{Aut}(X)$ is an uncountable group. So $\text{Aut}(X)$ cannot possibly be isomorphic to $A*B$.