# Generating set of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A subset $S$ of a group $G$ is said to be a generating set for $G$ if all elements of G can be expressed as the FINITE product of elements in S and their inverses. Why is it necessary to take only finite expressions ? Is there a group $G$ and a set $S$, where not all elements of $G$ can be written as a finite expression taken from the set $S$ ?

Comment: How do you define infinite product? Group operation is binary, and by induction and associativity it can be extended to $n$-ary operation but not infinitary.

Comment: If you allow infinite expressions, then $\mathbb{R} = \langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ as a ring. Or $\mathbb{R} = \langle\mathbb{Q}\rangle$ as a group.

Comment: @RandomJack I suppose you can do it in a similar way as one deals with ordinals. Or, perhaps most intuitively, one could consider an "element" as an element of the cartesian product $\prod S$. In this view, "standard" group elements have all but finitely many entries equal to the identity (clearly such a representation is not unique).

Comment: (I should say that I cannot really explain why I said "most intuitively", above, but perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/881397/10513) answer of mine explains what I mean a bit - viewing infinite products as an element of the Cartesian product would allow a finitely generated group to be the whole automorphism group of the tree in the question.)

Comment: There would be a problem with associativity:
$$1-1+1-1+1-1\ldots = (1-1)+(1-1)+\ldots = 0+0+0\ldots = 0$$
But
$$1-1+1-1+1-1\ldots = 1-(1-1)-(1-1)+\ldots = 1+0+0\ldots = 1$$

Comment: @user1729: Of course you can. But that would be outside of classic universal algebra which deals with algebras endowed with finitary operations. The notion of subgroup generated by a set changes significantly (if you add infinitary operation to the initial set of operations) which is demonstrated by Darth Geek's examples.

Comment: @RandomJack "...that would be outside of classic universal algebra..." I interpreted that to be the point of the question! If we leave normal algebra, where do we go? Where can we go?...

Comment: @DarthGeek: This is not correct ("as a ring"). You mean "as a topological ring". You cannot even formulate infinite products or sums for abstract rings.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No, I ment that if infinite sums or products are allowed, then you have those equalities, the first one as a ring and the second one as a group. Wich are nonsense, since infinite products or sums re not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

A group is a set $G$ together with binary operation that is a map from $G\times G $ to $G$ satisfying some set of axioms. It means that you are allowed to apply this operation to the pairs of elements only. The product of arbitrary finite number of elements is defined by induction: $a_1 \dots a_{n-1}a_n = (a_1 \dots a_{n-1})a_n$. If you want to form infinite (e.g. countable) products of elements you should define a map from the direct power $G^{\mathbb{N}}$ (the set of all functions $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to G$) to $G$, which can be done in many different ways. The main point here is that operation of finite product can be represented (to be written as a term) using only binary product, while infinitary one can not. With this additional operation you get the new structure, that is a group endowed with infinitary operation.

The definition of a subgroup in this structure differs from the usual one. A subgroup of a group $G$ is a subset of $G$ closed under the product operation (which is equivalent to be closed under arbitrary finite products) and taking the inverse element. While the subgroup of a group endowed with infinitary operation should be closed under this infinitary operation too. In order to see the difference look at Darth Geek's example in comments.

For the second question take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ with usual addition operation and $S = \{2\}$. You can't write $1$ as a finite expression of elements of $S$. Taking all possible finite expressions you will get the set of all even numbers $2\mathbb{Z}$, it is the subgroup generated by $S$.